# Count of the result of a MongoDB aggregate query

Tags: mongodb

After I write a MongoDB aggregate command, I would like to quickly look at the number of results it returned.

Say, my query is something like this: (probably more complex)

```
db.zipcodes.aggregate( [{ $group :
                            { _id : "$state" } }])
```

Then, right now I do the following to get a total count:

```
 db.zipcodes.aggregate( [{ $group :
                            { _id : "$state" }},
                         {'$group': {_id: null, count: {$sum: 1}}}])
```

Is there another quicker way to get a count of the results of a MongoDB aggregate query?

PS: I've just seen a related question: [MongoDB Aggregation: How to get total records count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348093/mongodb-aggregation-how-to-get-total-records-count) . Has there been any progress regarding this?

Comment: Well for MongoDB versions prior to 2.6 the result is always returned as an array, it can optionally be returned as a cursor in recent versions. As such this is all your robomongo interface is doing, by getting the "length" of the array returned. You can do the same thing to.

Comment: can you tell me how to get the length of the array when using something like the first query in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround I found so far is to use a MongoDB GUI such as Robomongo. It reports the size of the Result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
db.zipcodes.aggregate( [{ $group :
                        { _id : "$state" } },
{
  $count: "total" 
} 
])
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.