# Feathersjs before hook custom query to override result and maintain pagination

Tags: feathersjs

I have setup a before hook so that if a query param of search is present a custom Mongoose aggregation query is run to find Orders by customer details like...

```
module.exports = function(hook, next) {
  if (hook.params.query && hook.params.query.search) {
  let search = hook.params.query.search;
  let regEx = new RegExp(".*" + search + ".*", "i");
  delete hook.params.query.search;

  const OrderModel = hook.app.service("orders").Model;
  OrderModel.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "customeraddress",
      localField: "shipping_address",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "shipping_address"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "customeraddress",
      localField: "billing_address",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "billing_address"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "shipping_address.first_name": regEx
        },
        {
          "shipping_address.last_name": regEx
        },
        {
          "shipping_address.email": regEx
        },
        {
          "billing_address.first_name": regEx
        },
        {
          "billing_address.last_name": regEx
        },
        {
          "billing_address.email": regEx
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]).then(orders => {
  hook.result = orders;
  next();
});
} else {
next();
}
};
```

which works fine in the sense that it returns the orders, but the problem is I lose the attributes on the result for pagination which would normally be

```
{
  "total": 2453,
  "limit": 25,
  "skip": 0,
  "data": []
}
```

So how can I do a custom query like this whilst maintaining the same response structure. Is this something I need to do myself or is there an alternative way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

That is to be expected because you are using directly the mongoose `Model` for that service.

The service `find` method is the one generating those extra info. It does a [count](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-mongoose/blob/master/src/service.js#L100) to give you total. Then limit and skip is from your filters. That is why if you do $paginate false then you will only get an array of data without those total, skip, limit.

You can do a count by doing `yourservice.find({query: {...,$limit: 0}})` or with your aggregate, you need to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348093/mongodb-aggregation-how-to-get-total-records-count?answertab=votes#tab-top).

So you need to do it yourself.