# How do I count all the documents in a collection and use the cont in a controller, with MongoDB and Express.js?

Tags: mongodb, express, mean-stack

I am working on a **[blogging application](https://github.com/Ajax30/XPressBlog)** (click the link to see the **GitHub** repo) with Express (version 4.17.1), [EJS](https://ejs.co/) and MongoDB (version 4.0.10).

Trying to paginate the posts I did the following, in the controller:

```
exports.getPosts = (req, res, next) => {

    const perPage = 5;

    const currPage = req.query.page ? parseInt(req.query.page) : 1;

    let postsCount = 0;

    const posts = Post.find({}, (err, posts) => {

            postsCount = posts.length;

            let pageDecrement = currPage > 1 ? 1 : 0;

            let pageIncrement = postsCount >= perPage ? 1 : 0;

            if (err) {
                console.log('Error: ', err);
            } else {
                res.render('default/index', {
                    moment: moment,
                    layout: 'default/layout',
                    website_name: 'MEAN Blog',
                    page_heading: 'XPress News',
                    page_subheading: 'A MEAN Stack Blogging Application',
                    currPage: currPage,
                    posts: posts,
                    pageDecrement: pageDecrement,
                    pageIncrement: pageIncrement
                });
            }
        })
        .sort({
            created_at: -1
        })
        .populate('category')
        .limit(perPage)
        .skip((currPage - 1) * perPage);
};
```

And in the view:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary <%= pageDecrement == 0 ? 'disabled' : '' %>" href="/?page=<%= currPage - pageDecrement %>">&larr; Newer Posts</a>
```

and

```
<a class="btn btn-primary <%= pageIncrement == 0 ? 'disabled' : '' %>" href="/?page=<%= currPage + pageIncrement %>">Older Posts &rarr;</a>
```

That works fine unless there are is a number of posts equal to `perPage x N`, where N is an integer, in which case the "Older Posts" button becomes disabled one page too late.

That is because `postsCount = posts.length` counts the posts *after* they are limited by `.skip((currPage - 1) * perPage)`.

So I need to count the posts from the model/collection and bring that count variable *in* the controller.

My model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    short_description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    full_text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    category: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category'
    },
    post_image: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

How do I count all the documents in the posts collection and use that number in the posts controller?

Comment: Please use aggregate function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done easier with mongodb aggregation framework.

We use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) aggregation to get the paginated data along with the total number of documents.

In aggregation framework we use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) instead of mongoose populate. $lookup returns an array, to get the first item in array we use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) operator inside [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/).

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/47G5L9OqIjl)

And here is the code to apply to your app:
(The first $match aggregation is unnecessary here, but I put in in case you may need it in the future)

```js
exports.getPosts = async (req, res, next) => {
    const perPage = 5;
    const currPage = req.query.page ? parseInt(req.query.page) : 1;
    const skip = (currPage - 1) * perPage;

    try {
        const result = await Post.aggregate([{
                $match: {},
            },
            {
                $sort: {
                    created_at: -1,
                },
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "categories",
                    localField: "category",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "category",
                },
            },
            {
                $addFields: {
                    category: {
                        $arrayElemAt: ["$category", 0],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                $facet: {
                    totalRecords: [{
                        $count: "total",
                    }, ],
                    data: [{
                            $skip: skip,
                        },
                        {
                            $limit: perPage,
                        },
                    ],
                },
            },
        ]);

        let postsCount = result[0].totalRecords[0].total;
        const pageCount = Math.ceil(postsCount / perPage);
        const pageDecrement = currPage > 1 ? 1 : 0;
        const pageIncrement = currPage < pageCount ? 1 : 0;
        const posts = result[0].data;

        res.render("default/index", {
            moment: moment,
            layout: "default/layout",
            website_name: "MEAN Blog",
            page_heading: "XPress News",
            page_subheading: "A MEAN Stack Blogging Application",
            currPage,
            posts,
            pageDecrement,
            pageIncrement,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error: ", err);
        res.status(500).send("something went wrong");
    }
};
```

By the way, in the post schema, for date fields you use `default: Date.now()`, this  will cause the date value always the same value, it should be in this format: `default: Date.now`

Comment: I would rather not have that big `try`block in the controller. Is there a (simple) way to  get the `postsCount` variable *only* in the controller?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir we use try catch block to catch exceptions in async await syntax. Why does it cause a problem? Did you try my solution?

Comment: It does work, you did answer the question, but for the pagination to work correctly I must change the pagination logic itself. And I will in a minute.

Comment: Ok, now do you have any problem? I didn't made any changes in pageDecrement or pageIncrement since I thought there was no issue there.

Comment: Yes, the new code prevent the rendering of the single post because this part is now missing `const posts = Post.find({}, (err, posts) => {//more code })`. it was replaced by `const posts = result[0].data`. The post array should still pass through he model.

Comment: I didn't understand. Doesn't controller now returns all the data correctly? What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that my single pos si not displayed because the post id is no longer returned.

Comment: Which post do you mean? Is it about a different controller method?

Comment: No, it is `getPosts`. the `posts` object does no longer contain the post's id as a property. Try out the application without and with your code an you will see the difference.

Comment: All the posts are in the posts variable. It is an array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214738/discussion-between-razvan-zamfir-and-suleymansah).

Answer (score 3):

Read [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/).

> New in version 3.4.
>
> Processes multiple aggregation pipelines within a single stage on the
>   same set of input documents. Each sub-pipeline has its own field in
>   the output document where its results are stored as an array of
>   documents.

**Example:** See [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xXunC1vfV3S)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      "count": [
        { $match: {} },
        { $count: "totalCount" }
      ],
      "data": [
        { $match: {} },
        { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
        { $skip: 1 },
        { $limit: 2 }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

**Mongoose Version:**

```
Model.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      "count": [
        { $match: {} },
        { $count: "totalCount" }
      ],
      "data": [
        { $match: {} },
        { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
        { $skip: 1 },
        { $limit: 2 }
      ]
    }
  }
]).
then(res => console.log(res)).
catch(error => console.error('error', error));
```

Comment: Can you put your code in the context of mine? Thanks!

Comment: @RazvanZamfir check the Mongoose Version. Please make changes if you need to as I didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Mongoose you should use this:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-facet

Official Mongodb docs:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet

General idea is to perform aggregation instead of multiple calls (1 for getting needed info + 1 to get the total count of documents)

You can perform 2 separate calls of course but it will hit your performance (not much for small data volumes but still...)
So you can get all needed data with .find() and then get count like this:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.count

PS. btw, use async/await instead of callbacks to avoid callback hell